# How to do multitask learning using Caffe?

Tags: deep-learning, multitask-learning

I wonder how to do multitask learning using [Caffe](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe). Should I simply use the output layer [SigmoidCrossEntropyLoss](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/docs/tutorial/layers.md#sigmoid-cross-entropy) or [EuclideanLoss](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/docs/tutorial/layers.md#sum-of-squares--euclidean), and define more than one outputs?

---

E.g. is the following architecture valid (3 outputs, i.e. 3 tasks concurrently learnt)?

[image]

Corresponding prototxt file:

```
name: "IrisNet"
layer {
  name: "iris"
  type: "HDF5Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  hdf5_data_param {
    source: "iris_train_data.txt"
    batch_size: 1

  }
}

layer {
  name: "iris"
  type: "HDF5Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
  hdf5_data_param {
    source: "iris_test_data.txt"
    batch_size: 1

  }
}

layer {
  name: "ip1"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "ip1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
  }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 50
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
  }
}


layer {
  name: "ip2"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "ip1"
  top: "ip2"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
  }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
  }
}




layer {
  name: "loss"
  type: "SigmoidCrossEntropyLoss" 
  # type: "EuclideanLoss" 
  # type: "HingeLoss"  
  bottom: "ip2"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "loss"
}
```

Comment: Could you please add a wiki entry for "multitask-learning"?

Answer (score 1):

Every Blob in caffe can be assigned a nonzero loss weight.

And you can have an arbitrary number of outputs.

This means you can just learn n different networks on the same data with different targets and assign every loss function it's own weight. Caffe takes care of adding up all the loss.